# Bug with translate3d in Chrome v.44?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

Chrome 44 (44.0.2403.89 m) has just being released and I'm having troubles when using `translate3d`. (in both Mac and Windows versions)

---

This is affecting plugins like [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) and therefore [thousands of pages](http://libscore.com/#$.fn.fullpage) at the moment. 
([Opened issue at fullpage.js github](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/1389))

---

It seems to me that when applying two different translate values to the same element consecutively after a short period of time, it restarts its position to 0 when I apply the new value, causing the previous transition to get missed.

I was not able to isolate it completely and reproduce it as clean as I would have liked to, but this is as far as I could do:

http://jsfiddle.net/9ksx000q/3/

To reproduce it, just scroll down. You'll notice how it goes back to the previous section on each scroll if you do it consecutively. 
E.g: you'll see the first red section twice.

If you open the same test with any other browser you won't see the problem.

The transitions being applied are the following ones in my case (they depend on the viewport size):

```
translate3d(0px, -641px, 0px);
translate3d(0px, -1282px, 0px);
translate3d(0px, -1923px, 0px);
```

But between the 1st and the 2nd, and the 3rd and the 4th it seems to go back to `translate3d(0,0,0);` causing the first section to be shown again and again as the starting point.

Comment: @misterManSam question updated.

Comment: I got this transitions applied: `translate3d(0px, -255px, 0px); translate3d(0px, -510px, 0px); translate3d(0px, -765px, 0px); translate3d(0px, -1020px, 0px)`

Comment: @Hackerman yeah, that depends on the size of the viewport. But the problem still there. What is relevant is that it goes back to the first section which is position 0,0,0.

Comment: yeah this is funky, but translates are plagued with funky issues like this, like nested translates on fixed/absolute elements get out-of-whack. Maybe instead of translating the whole container, you can just translate the two objects that will be moving on screen. You can have all the objects position absolute 100% off screen, and then translate the one you want to move to 0 while translating the other to -100%. This will also be less performance costing with less moving each time.

Comment: @RooWM I don't see it. You are suggesting to create two transitions over two elements while I'm just making one. Why would it be less performance costing?

Comment: depends on what you're putting in those containers that will really make the difference—every one of them is painted on each frame of that transform with your current use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you just calls it in a `animation frame`

http://jsfiddle.net/9ksx000q/4/

Guess the issue is that the animation and the position calculation is happening at the same time, which is causing things to get weird

```
requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    var dtop = element.position().top;

    element.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    canScroll = false;

    var translate3d = 'translate3d(0px, -' + Math.ceil(dtop) + 'px, 0px)';
    $('#container').css(getTransforms(translate3d));

    //after animations finishes we allow to scroll again
    setTimeout(function () {
        canScroll = true;
    }, 1000);    
    //1000s is the time set to the in the CSS for the container
    //transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out;
});
```

Comment: Very interesting! [I had to create a substitute for IE < 10](https://gist.github.com/alvarotrigo/530d5ff7a34e8d3463eb), as [it is not supported in all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=requestanimationframe) but it seems to be working fine! Thanks for it! (although the Chrome bug still need to be solved I believe)

Comment: A problem I'm seeing when applying this solution is that `requestAnimationFrame` breaks the synchrony and can lead to some troubles there.

Comment: Is there any reason why `requestAnimationFrame` should be applied now that the bug in Chrome is solved? Any insights on it?