# requestAnimationFrame with translate3d css3 animation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

As far as I know `requestAnimationFrame` was designed to deal with Javascript animations and replace in some way the use of intervals or timeouts.

[It just happens to be necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575177/bug-with-translate3d-in-chrome-v-44) in order to deal with CSS3 animations when using the latest verisons of Chrome due to what it seems to be [a bug in Chrome > v.43](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=513206) .

Having to use `requestAnimationFrame` breaks the synchrony of the program as it runs asynchronously. And therefore things like the following code won't make sense anymore:

```
var flag = false;
createCssAnimation();
flag = true; //executed before the previous function call
```

[Here's an example online](http://jsfiddle.net/imac/6p8s3tg1/)

Notice how the flag has the wrong value inside the `requestAnimFrame` function.

This is a very simple example, but it shows how dealing with flags can become a bit tedious when adding the asynchronous function `requestAnimFrame`.

In order for the previous portion of code to work, this is what I'm doing at the moment:

```
var flag;
requestAnimFrame(function(){
    flag = false;
});

createCssAnimation();

requestAnimFrame(function(){
    flag = true;
});
```

Is there any other better approach to it?
This doesn't look like the best solution when functions are being called in different levels.